# Reference Dependencies in VS2015 from wwwroot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I have an MVC Web API application created with VS2015 using the new preview `C# 6`.

The project by default comes with a `Dependencies` folder and a `wwwroot` folder. Both of these reside in the root of my project.

In the `wwwroot` I have an `index.html` which is trying to reference `angular.js` which can be found in the `Dependencies/Bower` folder (the actual path name is `$(project_rootDir)/bower_components/`.

So in my `index.html` I simply do:

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

When I start `IIS Express` and check what file the `index.html` is trying to load through console then I see it's trying to get it from:

```
localhost:5000/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

But the path should be:

```
localhost:5000/../bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

But it seems like it cannot reference JS files from outside of the `wwwroot` folder. So I'm sort of stuck. What can I do? I want to reference the JS files from the `Dependencies` folder from the `wwwroot` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files need to be copied to the wwwroot folder. I guess this should be happening automatically but I was having problems with this earlier as well. I followed the steps in this article to copy the relevent files.

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bower.html

The steps wernt exactly as described. Here's what I ended up doing:

1. Right click on gulpfile.js
2. Click on "Task Runner Explorer"
3. Double click on "Tasks -> Copy"
4. You should now see a "lib" folder in wwwroot with the necessary files.

Comment: It seems that copying the files is (currently) the only option.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This answer relates to the new Asp Net MVC Core 1.0 in Visual Studio 2015.

Just wanted to update this as it's taken me a while to do this and google keeps bringing me back here. Short answer is you **don't** have to copy anything to anywhere.

@rdans answer is right in saying to look at the link (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bower.html) the most crucial element for this question is that to add a bower configuration file as soon as you create a project.

There is a `.bowerrc` file that also gets created which is what copies the newly installed bower components to the wwwroot folder (currently set to `"directory": "wwwroot/lib"`).

You then have to follow the instructions to add the following code to the StartUp.cs file.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Then when you want to reference the file ensure you have a ~ at the start of the src url.

Hope this helps someone.